# How to separate many different words from a string (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing, substring

I've been struggling to figure out how to get a word, of unknown length, from a string, of unknown length, that I'm reading from a file. The words I want from the string are always separated by "." and/or "&" with the whole string being surrounded by quotes. EX: ".Word.Characters&Numeric&Letters.Typos&Mistypes." I know the location of each "." and "&" as well as how many times they occur.

I want to feed the words into an array Example[i][j] based on whether or not the words are separated by a "." or a "&". So words contained between "." would be set into the i column of the array and words linked by "&" into the j rows of the array.

The input string can contain a largely variable number of words. Meaning that there can be only one word of interest, or one hundred+.

I'd prefer to use arrays to solve this problem. From what I've read regex would be slow, but work. split() may also work, but I think I'd have to know what words to look for before hand.

From this String: ".Word.Characters&Numeric&Letters.Typos&Mistypes." I'd expect to get: (without worrying about which is a row or column)

[[Word],[null],[null]],

[[Characters],[Numbers],[Letters]],

[[Typos],[Mistypes],[null]]

From this String ".Alpha.Beta.Zeta&Iota." I'd expect to get:

[[Alpha],[null]],

[[Beta],[null]],

[[Zeta],[Iota]]

```
//NumerOfPeriods tells me how many word "sections" are in the string
//Stor[] is an array that holds the string index locations of "."
for(int i=0;i<NumberOfPeriods;i++)
{
    int length = Stor[i];
    while(Line.charAt(length) != '"')
    {
        length++;
    }
    Example[i] = Line.substring(Stor[i], length);
}
//This code can get the words separated by "." but not by "&"

//Stor[] is an array that holds all string index locations of '.'
//AmpStor[] is an array that holds all string index locations of '&'
int TotalLength = Stor[0];
int InnerLength = 0;
int OuterLength = 0;
while(Line.charAt(TotalLength) != '"')
{
    while(Line.charAt(OuterLength)!='.')
    {
        while(Line.charAt(InnerLength)!='&')
        {
            InnerLength++;
        }
        if(Stor[i] > AmpStor[i])
        {
            Example[i][j] = Line.substring(Stor[i], InnerLength);
        }
        if(Stor[i] < AmpStor[i])
        {
            Example[i][j] = Line.substring(AmpStor[i],InnerLength);
        }
            OuterLength++;
    }
}
//Here I run into the issue of indexing into different parts of the array i & j
```

Comment: My first consideration would be not to try and do it in one step, but maybe break down the issue over a number of steps, each one working within the results of the last step.  Another consideration is maybe looking at using one or more regular expressions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All your code above could be put into:  String test2 = ".Alpha.Beta.Zeta&Iota.";
        for (String s : test2.split("\\p{P}")) {
            System.out.println(s);
        } Consider how you construct your code as it is crucial for further development without side-effects.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve your problem (it's completely different from your code but it works).

First of all, remove the quotes and the leading and trailing non-word characters. This can be done using `replaceAll`:

```
String Formatted = Line.replaceAll( "(^\"[.&]*)|([.&]*\"$)", "" );
```

The regular expression in the first argument will match the double quotes at both ends and the leading and trailing `.`s and `&`s. The method will return a new string where the matched characters are removed, because the second argument is an empty string (it replaces with an empty string).

Now you can split this string at each `.` using the `split` method. You could only define your output array after this call:

```
String[] StringGroups = Formatted.split( "\\." );
String[][] Elements = new String[StringGroups.length][];
```

Use an escaped backslash (`\\`) before the point to indicate that it should split on `.`-characters, since this method takes in a regular expression (and just `.` splits on any non-newline character).

Now split each string in that array at each `&` using the same `split` method. Add the result directly to your `Elements` array:

```
// Loop over the array
int MaxLength = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < StringGroups.length; i ++ ) {
   String StrGroup = StringGroups[ i ];
   String[] Group = StrGroup.split( "&" );
   Elements[ i ] = Group;

   // Measure the max length
   if( Group.length > MaxLength ) {
       MaxLength = Group.length;
   }
}
```

A `\\` is not necessary for the input, since `&` just matches `&`-characters. Now you only have to fill in your data into an array. The `MaxLength` variable is for adding the `null` values to your array. If you don't want them, just remove them and you're done here.

If you want the `null` values however, loop over your elements array and copy the current rows into new arrays:

```
for( int i = 0; i < Elements.length; i ++ ) {
    String[] Current = Elements[ i ];
    String[] New = new String[ MaxLength ];

    // Copy existing values into new array, extra values remain null
    System.arraycopy( Current, 0, New, 0, Current.length );
    Elements[ i ] = New;
}
```

Now, the `Elements` array contains exactly what you wanted.

Here is the complete executable code:

```
public class StringSplitterExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        test( "\".Word.Characters&Numeric&Letters.Typos&Mistypes.\"" );
        System.out.println(); // Line between
        test( "\".Alpha.Beta.Zeta&Iota.\"" );
    }

    public static void test( String Line ) {
        String Formatted = Line.replaceAll( "(^\"[.&]*)|([.&]*\"$)", "" );
        String[] StringGroups = Formatted.split( "\\." );
        String[][] Elements = new String[StringGroups.length][];

        // Loop over the array
        int MaxLength = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < StringGroups.length; i ++ ) {
            String StrGroup = StringGroups[ i ];
            String[] Group = StrGroup.split( "&" );
            Elements[ i ] = Group;

            // Measure the max length
            if( Group.length > MaxLength ) {
                MaxLength = Group.length;
            }
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < Elements.length; i ++ ) {
            String[] Current = Elements[ i ];
            String[] New = new String[ MaxLength ];

            // Copy existing values into new array, extra values remain null
            System.arraycopy( Current, 0, New, 0, Current.length );
            Elements[ i ] = New;
        }

        for( String[] Group : Elements ) {
            for( String String : Group ) {
                System.out.print( String );
                System.out.print( " " );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this example:

```
Word null null 
Characters Numeric Letters 
Typos Mistypes null 

Alpha null 
Beta null 
Zeta Iota
```

So this works, and you don't even need to know where the `.` and `&` characters are in your string. Java will just do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to separate the string into substrings delimited by '.' and then for each of the substrings, separate it into subsubstrings delimited by '&'. If that's the case, then I would use the `split` method:

```
List<List<String>> terms = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\."))
    .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("\\&"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if you really need it to be returned as a null-padded array:

```
String[][] result = new String[terms.size()][ terms.stream.mapToInt(List::size).max().getAsInt()];
IntStream.range(0, terms.size()).forEach(i ->
    IntStream.range(0, terms.get(i).size()).forEach(j -> 
        result[i][j] = terms.get(i).get(j)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I tried to solve the problem:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class StringSplitSplits {

    private static final String S1 = ".Word.Characters&Numeric&Letters.Typos&Mistypes.";
    private static final String S2 = ".Alpha.Beta.Zeta&Iota.";

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String str = stripStartAndEndDots(S1);
        String [] ss = str.split("\\.");
        int maxLength = getMaxLength(ss);

        String [][] sss = Stream.of(ss)
                                .map(s -> s.split("&"))
                                .map(s -> Arrays.copyOf(s, maxLength))
                                .toArray(String[][]::new);
        Stream.of(sss).forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
    }

    private static String stripStartAndEndDots(String input) {
        if (input.startsWith(".")) {
            input = input.substring(1);
        }
        if (input.endsWith(".")) {
            input = input.substring(0, input.length()-1);
        }
        return input;
    }

    /*
     * Get max length of the arrays split on the "&" for each
     * string element of the input string array.
     */
    private static int getMaxLength(String [] input) {
        return Stream.of(input)
                        .map(s -> s.split("&"))
                        .mapToInt(ss -> ss.length)
                        .max()
                        .orElse(0);
    }
}
```

Input: `".Word.Characters&Numeric&Letters.Typos&Mistypes."`

Output:

```
[Word, null, null]
[Characters, Numeric, Letters]
[Typos, Mistypes, null]
```

Input: `".Alpha.Beta.Zeta&Iota."`

Output:

```
[Alpha, null]
[Beta, null]
[Zeta, Iota]
```